# Solving Brute force algorithm without itertools function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-itertools, brute-force

Assuming *1211* and *"baba"* is your pin and password.

Write two different functions that keeps looping until it gets the pin and password respectively.

i managed to write something using the itertools function but my tutor said not to use it and i should look for another way, i've only been coding for two weeks, so my understanding of python isn't wide and would really appreciate some advice. I'm really sorry about how messy my question is, this is my first time using this.

```
    import itertools
    import string

    for guess in itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=6):
      if checkguess(''.join(guess)):
        print("Password is: {0}".format(''.join(guess)))
```

Comment: Can you add what you've tried within `itertools` module ?

Comment: If you're *given* the PIN and password, why do you need to loop at all?  The problem description is not yet clear.  Also, post your best attempt so far -- you haven't given us *any* code, and it appears that you haven't tried to solve this problem on your own.

Comment: Simply replacing the `itertools` routines shouldn't be the problem: those algorithms are easily found in the browser search you *should* have performed before posting.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for-loop` to try different combinations and find the pin or password, this is an example for the PIN:

```
pin = 1211
rng = int(len(str(pin)) * str(9))
for i in xrange(rng):
    if i == pin:
        print('pin is: {}'.format(i))
        break
```

you can start with it and try to figure out how to do the rest :)

Comment: Thank you, i think i know exactly what to do now.

Comment: @Simi.i Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful =)